# Batch edit multiple text files with number sequence

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have 100's of .xml files (TV show based) that are named sequentially like so:

```
s07e01.xml
s07e02.xml
s07e03.xml
s07e04.xml
```

The season and number of episodes (per season) differ.

In each file there are two lines:

```
<ID></ID>
<EpisodeNumber></EpisodeNumber>
```

Is it possible to batch edit these files adding the episode number to these two elements?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the input data going to come from?

Comment: Could be the episode (e##) digits from the file name. All the files are in alphanumeric order in each directory (sorted by name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very efficient and elegant solution using [REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs a regular expression search/replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. REPL.BAT is pure script that will run natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is built into the script.

I use REPL.BAT twice. First to modify the output of DIR /B, filtering out lines that don't match the name template, and also extracting the Season and Episode values. The result is processed by FOR /F. Then for each file, a second REPL.BAT modifies the actual file and writes it to a temp file. Finally, the temp file is MOVEd to the original file name. The 2nd REPL makes both replacements in one pass. The replacement value is a JScript expression that determines which value to plug in, depending on the matched tag name.

This script will process all files in the current folder:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2*" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d s??e*.xml^|repl "^s(\d\d)e(\d\d)" "$1:$2:$&" ia'
) do (
  type "%%C"|repl "(<(ID|EpisodeNumber)>).*?(</\2>)" "$1+($2=='ID'?'%%A':'%%B')+$3" j >"%%C.new"
  move /y "%%C.new" "%%C" >nul
)
```

This second version will process an entire folder hierarchy. It only requires a slight modification to the DIR command and the initial REPL search string:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2*" %%A in (
  'dir /b /s /a-d s??e*.xml^|repl "^.*\\s(\d\d)e(\d\d)" "$1:$2:$&" ia'
) do (
  type "%%C"|repl "(<(ID|EpisodeNumber)>).*?(</\2>)" "$1+($2=='ID'?'%%A':'%%B')+$3" j >"%%C.new"
  move /y "%%C.new" "%%C" >nul
)
```

Comment: Elegant indeed. This does the job exactly as needed, with or without the episode name. Also, it will input the correct data if something else is present. dbenham, thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in *.xml ; do
    n=${f##*/s}; n=${n#*e}; n=${n%.xml}
    echo "File $f --> episode $n" >&2
    mv -f "$f" "$f.bak"
    while IFS= read -r line ; do
        if [[ "$line" == *"<ID>"*"</ID>"* ]]; then
            echo -e "${line%%[^ ]*}<ID>$n</ID>\r"
        elif [[ "$line" == *"<EpisodeNumber>"*"</EpisodeNumber>"* ]]; then
            echo -e "${line%%[^ ]*}<EpisodeNumber>$n</EpisodeNumber>\r"
        else
            echo -e "$line\r"
        fi
    done < "$f.bak" >| "$f"
done
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: You may install cygwin and run the script in the cygwin console.

Comment: Google just informed me of that. Edouard a big thank you for the help. You wrote that script faster than I could explain myself. I will give it a try.

Comment: If she had wanted to use bash, she would have added the bash tag.

Comment: It works in the current directory. If you want to run it in subdirectories, replace `for f in *.xml` by `for f in */*.xml`

Comment: @SomethingDark yes but bash is so handy.

Comment: Edouard thanks again... I don't mean to push your suggestion to the side but... SomethingDark if you could convert what Edouard suggested for me, I would rather not install Cygwin.

Comment: Edouard I finally figured out how to make the script work. It works as it should but... It completely changes the format of the file. There is many other elements within the file and  is formatted a certain way. The script combines all elements into one line.

Comment: @HeatherBrown ok I have fixed the script to keep the spaces and lines.

Comment: Your fix keeps all other lines formatted perfectly but... I just noticed that your original and modified script deletes the very last line in the file.

Comment: I reinstalled Cygwin from a different download site and all is perfect. Your script will save me many hours of manual editing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Edouard one last thing. Sometimes the file name can have the title of the episode, e.g. s02e01 - show one, s02e01 - show two. Right now the script will input <ID>01 - show one</ID>. Is there something I could change in the script to avoid all characters after episode number?

Comment: Edouard, I wanted to thank you for opening up the world of bash scripting to me. Though you provided a solution to what I had asked, I'm gonna go with dbenham's solution. He, so to speak, jumped up to first and won the race. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all .xml files
for %%f in (*.xml) do (
   rem Get season and episode in %%a and %%b
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=se." %%a in ("%%f") do (
      rem Get the numbers of both target lines
      set "repLines=/"
      for /F "delims=:" %%c in ('findstr "<ID> <EpisodeNumber>" "%%f"') do (
         set "repLines=!repLines!%%c/"
      )
      rem Initialize the (first) replacement string
      set "replace=<ID>%%a</ID>"
      rem Process the file, replace values, create new file
      (for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%c in ('findstr /N "^" "%%f"') do (
         rem If this is a target line
         if "!repLines:/%%c/=!" neq "!repLines!" (
            rem Do the replacement
            echo !replace!
            rem And change to next (second) replacement string
            set "replace=<EpisodeNumber>%%b</EpisodeNumber>"
         ) else (
            rem Output the line unchanged
            setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
            set "line=%%d"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo(!line!
            endlocal & endlocal
         )
      )) > "%%~Nf.tmp"
   )
)

rem Update files
del *.xml
ren *.tmp *.xml
```

Previous solution assume that there are just two lines with `<ID></ID>` and `<EpisodeNumber></EpisodeNumber>` values placed in that order. If this is not true, a small modification is needed.

Comment: to my experience, the`s` and `e` is sometimes captials, sometimes not. Therefore I would set `delims=sSeE.`

Comment: Thanks for jumpin' in Aacini. The script you generously offered modifies the file (changes modified date) but it does not make any changes..?

Answer (score 0):

simple batch script:

```
@echo off

REM rename all files with matching patterns to tmp-files:
ren s??e??.xml *.tmp

REM for all tmp-files do:
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.tmp') do (
  REM get season and episode:
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=SsEe." %%i in ("%%~nf") do (
    REM write new xml file:
    >%%~dpnf.xml echo ^<ID^>%%i^</ID^>
    >>%%~dpnf.xml echo ^<EpisodeNumber^>%%j^</EpisodeNumber^>
  )
)
REM delete tmp files:
del *.tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, but it deletes the rest of the text in file. There is many other elements within the file and formatted a certain way.

Comment: sorry, I understood "In each file there are two lines"

Comment: Try @Aacini's solution. I didn't try it, but it looks good and should do what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry too. I was pointing out directly the two lines I needed to edit. This scripting stuff is "Greek" to me so any help is appreciated.